# How to create a directory hard link in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, filesystems, hardlink

I was trying to create a directory hard link (not a symbolic one).

I've tried this: `mklink /d /h newfolder currentfolder` but it's telling me *Access is denied*. I don't understand how is access denied because I'm running batch as administrator.

How do we create a directory hard link?

==
Windows Vista Home Premium SP2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think that hard links are for files only and not directories.

Comment: Yes, there is no such thing as a directory hard link, only junction points and symbolic links.

Comment: Hardlinks for directories are *technically* possible, but need great care to avoid loops in the filesystem. The only OS which allows them is Mac OS X 10.5, for use in Time Machine.

Comment: > I think that hard links are for files only and not directories. Thanks for the confirmation; I keep intending to read up on symlinks and such: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Book&bookcmd=download&collection_id=e265612de20e02b0&writer=rl&return_to=Special%3ABook) [2](http://wesnerm.blogs.com/net_undocumented/2006/10/symbolic_links_.html) [3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006(v=VS.85).aspx) [4](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/ntfs/filesReparse-c.html)

Comment: well... under linux-systems you can use `mount --bind` for folders but i'm not sure if there is something similar in windows!

Answer (score 30):

There is no such thing as a hard link to a directory in Windows. In Windows, you either create a *symbolic link* to a directory by using the command `mklink /d link_name target_dir` or you create a *junction* with `mklink /J link_name target_dir`.

Differently of hard links, junctions may span multiple volumes and are sometimes called "soft links" by Microsoft, as you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A junction (also called a *soft link*) differs from a hard link in that the storage objects it references are separate directories, and a junction can link directories located on different local volumes on the same computer.

Some caveat is required here since Microsoft's nomenclature is not really neat but, in a few words, these are your options to create references to files and directories in Windows:
**(1)** shortcuts: files whose content is the location of another file. It works more or less like a soft link, with a crucial difference though: it is NOT a directory entry, the link information is stored inside the file. For this reason, it doesn't work with many applications (at least, it works as it is supposed to within the Windows Explorer...);
**(2)** hard links: created with the command `mklink /h`. Valid for files only and works within a given volume (i.e., just like in Linux, you cannot hard-link a file in another partition nor in a network drive);
**(3)** junctions: this beast is really weird. It works with directories only, and - funny thing - can point to directories in other file systems;
**(4)** symbolic links: it is much like in Linux, and works with directories and files, too. (But tends to require Administrator privileges, which can make it rather inconvenient.) As I mentioned above, it is created with the command `mklink /d link_name target_dir` for directories (and `mklink link_name target_file` for files).
You can read more about this [here](https://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/).

Comment: Humberto, I kinda like your answer, but there are two problems: 1. The "Otherwise, junctions operate identically to hard links" part in the MSDN quote is dangerously wrong: a profound difference is that a hard link behaves identically to its "target" (or "sibling", actually...) file in that no matter which one you delete, the other will stay unaffected. Junctions (like other _soft links_) lack this important symmetry. 2. The reference to Joseph's answer makes no sense. +1: "things you can create to point to file system entities (files and directories)" should be "... (files or directories)".

Comment: @Sz you were totally right, and I modified my answer according to your comments (indeed, the answer was a bit fuzzy). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! I failed to point out in my prev. comment that distancing junctions from _soft_ (or _sym-_) links and trying to relate them to _hard_ links instead ("It is like a hard link, ...") is still a bit off. Junctions really are soft links, in fact they are very much _unlike_ hard links in almost every respect. (Hard links are low-level filesystem objects quite transparent to fs. operations, and e.g. can't "break", once created, unlike other link types that are called "soft" exactly for this reason.) (I'll edit the a. to show what I mean, feel free to reject/adjust. Cheers!)

Comment: Instead of `target`, we could use `source` here which resolves the confusion

Comment: Not sure who needs to read this but in these modern Powershell-mostly times, this only worked for me from `cmd.exe`, and even for the soft link from a directory in user home to another directory in same user home (same partition) I needed to run `cmd.exe` as Administrator! But it worked, thank  you