# How can I create a hard link to a directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, ntfs, hardlink

A comment at [How to create a directory hard link in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/343072/how-to-create-a-directory-hard-link-in-windows#comment375906_343076) states it is "technically possible" to create a hard link to a directory, but so far I have not found anything about how to implement this. Is there a way to do this in Windows 10? I don't mind using third party software, but I don't want a symbolic link or a junction point.

Comment: The comment doesn't say you can create them on Windows – just that they aren't impossible as a concept and that certain _other_ operating systems have successfully implemented them.

Comment: @user1686 That makes sense. Although I still am not sure what makes them impossible on Windows. If I created one on a USB on another OS that supported creating them, and opened the USB on Windows, would it recognise the hard link? Or does Windows just not have the code to deal with them at all?

Comment: @potato-burger Does NTFS even support directory hard links, as it doesn't [appear](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) Windows does since a [hard link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc788097(v=ws.11)#remarks) is a directory entry for a file?

Comment: @JW0914 That was supposed to be a part of my question. I wasn't sure if directory hard links were completely unsupported in NTFS, or if there was just something blocking them from being created on Windows. As this question is closed, (which is my fault for not making the question clear enough), I'll create a new question that is explained clearer.

Comment: @potato-burger For what purpose are you trying to create a directory hard link over a symbolic link?

Comment: @JW0914 Symbolic links and junction points have shortcut arrows on them, and I didn't want a shortcut arrow.

Comment: @potato-burger There are a few ways to remove the shortcut arrow, but I can't remember how to do so natively in Windows since I've used Stardock's [IconPackager](https://www.stardock.com/products/iconpackager/) for years to do so. The arrow is a secondary overlay over the icon, separate from the main icon.